# Why does Boost.Hana use macros for opening/closing namespaces?

Tags: c++, boost, macros, namespaces, boost-hana

One of the many examples of two macros being used to open and close a `namespace` respectively is in `/usr/include/boost/hana/transform.hpp`:

```cpp
BOOST_HANA_NAMESPACE_BEGIN
// stuff
BOOST_HANA_NAMESPACE_END
```

Those macros are defined like this in `/usr/include/boost/hana/config.hpp`:

```cpp
#define BOOST_HANA_NAMESPACE_BEGIN namespace boost { namespace hana {

#define BOOST_HANA_NAMESPACE_END }}
```

What is the advantage of doing so?

(Considering that there's at least one disvantage: that it makes it harder to jump back and forth from beginning to end of `namespace`s.)

Comment: Good question, but I think the only person that can honestly answer this question is Louis Dionne.  Anyone else's answer would be speculative.  My speculation is that Louis doesn't like the `namespace` syntax because it makes his editor auto-indent the entire namespace block.

Comment: @Eljay That would be a yikes...

Comment: maybe this is some boost rule - that libraries shall try to be supported by compilers not supporting namespaces. You might ask on some boost community

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/288

Comment: @Eljay, here we have Louis Dionne's answer :)

Comment: Excellent!  And see, my highly speculative speculation was completely wrong.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was originally for forward compatibility with using inline namespaces, however this never became relevant. I re-opened https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/288 and will change it to normal namespace declarations.